# How do I check that a Rest call is successful in unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to invoke a rest Url from Unix shell and verify that call is successful based on return code. 
If the call fails, I would like the details to be stored in a variable.

I have tried various options in cURL.

Comment: Depends on the API. You will likely have to include headers in the output and then parse out the HTTP status header, looking for a 2** value.

Comment: You can use curl's `-w` option to print out a message that includes the http response number to standard output, which you can read and do stuff with.